# CSS order for multiple HTML files

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a navbar with a few links and I'm not completely sure if I should make a CSS file for each of the pages. E.I: There's the "About", "Shop" and "Contact" sections but they have the same background (which I wanna change). My question is: To make all of the website's sections share the same navbar I got to make a CSS file for each HTML file and paste the navbar code on all of the previously mentioned files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all CSS code within one file
or
you can separate it into multiple and copy the code.

I would prefer putting all in one because.this will cut down the size of the project.

Of there is more to it, let me know

Edit:
Link the CSS to the HTML pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss.css" />
```

Comment: Well, I'd like to have all the CSS in a single file but I don't really know how to make it work for separated HTML files, for example, I made the homepage and I'm working on the "About" page but it has the same background image because I made the background image on CSS using the "html" tag like this `html { 
    background: url(../imagez/bwHP.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }`

Comment: All you would have to do is link the CSS file into ALL of the HTML pages wanted. See my answer edit to see the code. Just one CSS file can be linked to all HTML files. This works because only one HTML file calls on the CSS file at a time.

Comment: I made a background div with 100% width and height so I can keep working with a single CSS file that contains all the website's style code. Very nice of you, hope you have a nice day. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! 